# how to do file upload using jquery serialization

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, serialization, file-upload

So I have a form and I'm submitting the form through ajax using jquery serialization function

```
        serialized = $(Forms).serialize();

        $.ajax({

        type        : "POST",
        cache   : false,
        url     : "blah",
        data        : serialized,
        success: function(data) {

        }
```

but then what if the form has an `<input type="file">` field....how do I pass the file into the form using this ajax serialization method...printing $_FILES doesn't output anything

Answer (score 52, accepted):

A file cannot be uploaded using AJAX because you cannot access the contents of a file stored on the client computer and send it in the request using javascript. One of the techniques to achieve this is to use hidden iframes. There's a nice [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) which allows you to AJAXify your forms and it [supports file uploads](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload) as well. So using this plugin your code will simply look like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#ifoftheform').ajaxForm(function(result) {
        alert('the form was successfully processed');
    });
});
```

The plugin automatically takes care of subscribing to the `submit` event of the form, canceling the default submission, serializing the values, using the proper method and handle file upload fields, ...

Comment: This is no longer true. With a <input type='file' name='myfile'/> and the FormData() object, one can save a file using AJAX very simply. See Silver89's answer below.

Comment: @Rook777, that's of course true if the browser you are using supports the HTML5 File API. Have you tried this in IE how simple it is? Until HTML5 becomes a standard and supported by all browsers there will be plugins because you cannot upload files using AJAX.

Comment: You are correct. I am lucky enough to be in a development environment that does not support IE so I forgot to consider it. Yes, without HTML5 compatibility, this feature will not work. According to http://caniuse.com/xhr2, only IE 10+ supports this feature so far.

Comment: jQuery Form Plugin is great!

Answer (score 90):

Use `FormData` object.It works for any type of form

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        type: $(this).attr("method"),
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: new FormData(this),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data, status)
        {

        },
        error: function (xhr, desc, err)
        {
            

        }
    });        

});
```

Comment: Important note on this: `processData: false, contentType: false,` is needed to avoid an `Illegal invocation` error, as without these, jQuery will try to convert the formdata to a string when sending it, which is not wanted in this case.

Comment: But this is when you only want to upload a file. What if our form has input fields as well. Is there a way to use FormData() when we have a file and input fields in our form? doing `processData: false, contentType: false` will not convert input fields data into String.

Answer (score 34):

```
   var form = $('#job-request-form')[0];
        var formData = new FormData(form);
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/send_resume/", // the endpoint
            type: "POST", // http method
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: formData,
```

It worked for me! just set processData and contentType False.

Answer (score 25):

**HTML**

```
<form name="my_form" id="my_form" accept-charset="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return false">
    <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" type="text" value="">
    <textarea id="detail" name="detail" placeholder="Enter Detail"></textarea>
    <select name="gender" id="gender">
        <option value="male" selected="selected">Male</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
    </select>
    <input type="file" id="my_images" name="my_images" multiple="" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg"/>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var data = new FormData();

//Form data
var form_data = $('#my_form').serializeArray();
$.each(form_data, function (key, input) {
    data.append(input.name, input.value);
});

//File data
var file_data = $('input[name="my_images"]')[0].files;
for (var i = 0; i < file_data.length; i++) {
    data.append("my_images[]", file_data[i]);
}

//Custom data
data.append('key', 'value');

$.ajax({
    url: "URL",
    method: "post",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
        //success
    },
    error: function (e) {
        //error
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST);
    print_r($_FILES);
    echo '</pre>';
    die();
?>
```

Comment: How to send submit button name?

Comment: @MuhammadTarique You just add button like `<button type="button" name="button_name" value="Contact Button">Submit</button>` and you get response button_name = "Contact Button" at php side

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I don't think it will work this way. However I've already done this by using `formData.append("btnName", "true");`

Comment: @MuhammadTarique This example already added in this post like `data.append('key', 'value');`

Answer (score 14):

You can upload files via AJAX by using the FormData method. Although IE7,8 and 9 do not support FormData functionality.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php", 
    type: "POST",             
    data: new FormData('form'),
    contentType: false,       
    cache: false,             
    processData:false, 
    success: function(data) {
        $("#response").html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: what is 'form' in   new FormData('form')  ,is it the id, it doesn't work for me

Comment: Yes this would typically be the form id

Comment: to me it works only with  document.forms.form  instead of 'form' string, passed to the FormData constructor

Answer (score 14):

```
$(document).on('click', '#submitBtn', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
var form = $("#myForm").closest("form");
var formData = new FormData(form[0]);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    dataType: "json",
    url: form.attr('action'),
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data) {
         alert('Sucess! Form data posted with file type of input also!');
    }
)};});
```

By making use of `new FormData()` and setting `processData: false, contentType:false` in ajax call submission of form with file input worked for me

**Using above code I am able to submit form data with file field also through Ajax**

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 introduces `FormData` class that can be used to file upload with ajax.

FormData support starts from following desktop browsers versions. IE 10+, Firefox 4.0+, Chrome 7+, Safari 5+, Opera 12+

[FormData - Mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)