# Submit HTML Form with fields and file using Ajax and php

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, file-upload

I am a newbie in web development. I working on a project where the site has a Career page where the details ie name, sex, etc with a resume has to be submitted.

I have implemented it using Ajax and Jquery, but the problem is I am not getting the file details in the PHP when the form is submitted.

Comment: did you mean the complete $_POST is empty?

Comment: I am getting a 404 error when browsing to your HTML page! Assuming the source isn't huge, you might just want to paste it into your question.

Comment: You will not be able to upload a file using jQuery's $.ajax() function this way. You can find external libraries to help you do this, either via the iFrame method or whatever other way.. The jQuery Form plugin have a nice implementation of what you seek: [http://jquery.malsup.com/form/](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)

Answer (score 0):

do you use `<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">`?

Start debugging by printing everyting with `var_dump($_POST)` or `print_r($_POST)`

Answer (score 0):

You said you're newbie, i will recommend you to learn any php framework such as `Codeigniter` for this stuff instead of messing up with your code [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com)

You will end up saying that `is PHP that easy?`

Answer (score 0):

add the  action='formular.php' ... like

```
<form id="contactform" name="contactform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="your_php_file.php>
```

Comment: its giving error even after adding it Notice: Undefined index: file_upload in D:\wamp\www\baldev\upload.php on line 9

Comment: Even if the enctype was set for the form $.ajax() will not allow him to upload the file! [Answer provided previously here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545081/how-do-to-file-upload-using-jquery-serialization)