# How to transmit file from JavaScript via Ajax to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form where a user enters his name and selects a profile picture. These information and the avatar should be added to the mysql db via ajax and php.

**HTML**:

```
<form id="addWorkerForm" action="addWorker.php" method="post">
  Prename:<input type="text" name="prename" id="prename">
  Lastname:<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">
  Image:<input type="file" id="file_input" name="file_input" >
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var prename = $('#prename').val();    
var lastname = $('#lastname').val();    
var workerAvatar = $('#file_input').val();

var url = 'xyz/addWorker.php?prename=' + prename + '&lastname=' + lastname + '&avatar=' + workerAvatar;

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {

    }
});
```

Is this the proper way to access the file in order to get its content in javascript? Furthermore, how can I access the file in the php file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276916/asynchronous-file-upload-ajax-file-upload-using-jsp-and-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a very similar problem recently, had my question answered ([JQuery1.8.0: Sending files from forms via AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506855/jquery1-8-0-sending-files-from-forms-via-ajax/15693645#15693645)).

Long story short, you *can* send files via AJAX, but you need to use FormData() to do it because the file needs to be encoded into "multipart/form-data" which XmlHttpRequest has only recently become able to do (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData).

Should be something like:

```
<button id="ajaxUploadSubmit"> Submit </button>
<script>
var data    = new FormData(document.forms.namedItem("workerAddForm"));

$( "#ajaxUploadSubmit" ).click(function() {
    var oReq    = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("POST", "xyz/addwrker.php", true);
    oReq.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"); //necessary for my application, might not be for you, I'm using CakePHP

    oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {   
        //whatever you want with oReq.responseText
        }
    oReq.send(data);
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot upload a file by passing the value of the file to php unfortunately.  You will either have to upload the file yourself or if you want to stay with the AJAX approach, use something like [Plupload](http://plupload.com)

What you can hope to get is a reference to the name of the file uploaded, and then store that in a `<input type="hidden" value="XXXXXXXX.jpg"/>` and pass that along as your `workerAvatar`.  Then when you load the page, just reference that in the `<img src="XXXXX.jpg"/>`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this [AjaxFileUpload](http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/) plugin