# Ajax serialize() method is not reading all data fields of html form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm trying to send the form data of my web page using jquery get() method. But when I submit the form only few of the field data where sent to the server.

Form:

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" id="addpost" method="GET" action="">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="form-field">Post Title</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="form-field" placeholder="Post Title" name="Post-title" value="" />
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="control-group">
         <label class="control-label" for="form-field-11">Content Here</label>
            <div class="controls">
            <textarea name="post-content"  value="" class="autosize-transition span12" id="form-field-11" style="overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; resize: horizontal; height: 67px;"></textarea>
            </div>
           </div><!-- Insert Image Code -->
           <div class="control-group">
            <div class="widget-main">
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="ace-file-input">
                        <input id="id-input-file-2" type="file">
                        <a class="remove" href="#"></a>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="controls">
                    <div class="ace-file-input ace-file-multiple">
                        <input id="id-input-file-3" type="file" multiple="">
                        <a class="remove" href="#">
                        <i class="icon-remove"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <label>
                    <input id="id-file-format" type="checkbox" name="file-format">
                        <span class="lbl"> Allow only images</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
              </div>
             </div><!-- Insert Image Code -->
            <div class="space-4"></div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="form-field-tags">Tag input</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input id="form-field-tags" type="hidden" placeholder="Enter tags ..." value="Tag Input Control" name="tags">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="space-4"></div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="form-field-select-3">Select Category</label>
                <div class="controls">
                <label for="form-field-select-3">Chosen</label>
                <select class="chzn-select" id="form-field-select-3" data-placeholder="Choose a Category...">
                <option value="">
                </option><option value="Blog">Blog
                </option><option value="News Letter">News Letter
                </option></select>
             </div>
           </div>

     <div class="control-group" style="float:left; margin-right:25px">
        <div class="controls"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">
        <i class="icon-ok bigger-110"></i>
        <input type="submit" value="" id="posubmit" style="opacity:0"/>Submit</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn"><i class="icon-undo bigger-110"></i>Reset</button>
        </div>
     </div> 
     <div id="resp" style="float:left; margin-top:5px">
        <img id="loading" style="visibility:hidden;" src="assets/img/ajax-load.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="loading" />
      </div>
     </form>
```

JavaSccript:

```
 $('#addpost').submit(function(e){ 
 if(use_ajax)
        {
            $('#loading').css('visibility','visible');
            $.get('test.php',$(this).serialize(),

                function(data){
                    if(parseInt(data)==-1)
                        $.validationEngine.buildPrompt("#resp","* Please ensure all fields are filled.","error");

                    else
                    {
                        $("#resp").show('slow').after('<p id="resp-mes" style=" color:#000000; text-decoration: bold;">Success....</p>');
                    }

                    $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
                     setTimeout( "jQuery('#resp').hide('slow');",3000 );
                     setTimeout( "jQuery('#resp-mes').hide('slow');",5000 );
                    });
        }
        e.preventDefault();
}
 )};
```

In  this only 3 field values where sent to server.
That is Post-title, post-content and tags 
I don't know why this happening. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you disabling any of the tags in the form at any time?

Comment: @pythonian29033 All tags in my form are always enabled, i didn't disabled any of those

Comment: If you don't have a `name` attribute in the input element, `serialize` doesn't know what to name it.

Comment: @Steve - I don't recall the last time I didn't include a `name` attribute... until tonight.  Beat my head on the wall for an hour before I came across your comment that `serialize` won't include a field without a `name`!  Makes sense.  Thank you very much for leaving your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have two issues.

1. Ajax and serialize upload doesn't work with file upload. ([Read this question and answer for async upload](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2320069/656539))
2. [jquery form serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) needs a name attribute. your select box (`form-field-select-3`) doesn't have a name attribute.

following is a note in [jquery serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) documentation page -

> Note: Only "[successful controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2)" are serialized to the string. No
>   submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted
>   using a button. For a form element's value to be included in the
>   serialized string, the element must have a name attribute. Values from
>   checkboxes and radio buttons (inputs of type "radio" or "checkbox")
>   are included only if they are checked. Data from file select elements
>   is not serialized.

Comment: damn you! I was typing so fast!

Comment: Stackoverflow dude. :)

Answer (score 4):

Its because you have missed "name" attribute in select element

`<select class="chzn-select" id="form-field-select-3" name="form-field-select-3" data-placeholder="Choose a Category...">`

I have checked in my local, and now this is working fine.

Please check and let me know if any issue.

Thanks

Comment: It works but file won't be sent. That because serialize won't support file (from Mohit Jain's Answer). Thanks

Comment: For that you can check this ans : [how-to-do-file-upload-using-jquery-serialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545081/how-to-do-file-upload-using-jquery-serialization)

Answer (score 2):

I see that attrbute `name=""` is required and some of the input elems are missing those. so you can try placing this attribute and see if this solves the issue:

```
 <select class="chzn-select" name="your-elem-name">
 //--------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-----try placing the name attr
```

Answer (score 1):

ok of this entire form, only four elements may get sent through if all four are populated/selected from a higher index than zero;
the ones with these names;
"tags"
"file-format"
"post-content"
"Post-title"

this is because those are the only tags with a name attribute defined.
please give all the elements you want to post through to the server a name attribute with the post index you want to use to access them with.