# Using Jasny file input to upload file to the server using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am implementing [Jasny File Input](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput) plugin. However, I can't get it upload to server.

HTML

```
<form method="post" id="formCreateMod" class="form form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form">
    <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
         <div class="fileinput-preview thumbnail" data-trigger="fileinput"></div>
         <div>
              <span class="btn btn-default btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new">Select image</span><span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span><input type="file" name="img"></span>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Delete</a>
         </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The above snippet is inside the `<form>` tag. Then I use post in jQuery to send the serialized data of the form to server.

I am expecting to get the content in php by using `$_FILES['img']["name"]` or `$_FILES['img']["type"]`, but the result is `NULL`.

So how should I retrieve the image data in php after the image is being posted?

Any help will be appreciated!

**Update**

The following is how I post the form in jQuery.

```
var theForm = $('form');
$.post(location.href, theForm.serialize(), function(data) {
    // handle return data
});
```

Comment: Can you post your `<form>` tag in your code as well ? (Yes, it is important)

Comment: @FlorianF. I don't quite get what you mean by post <form> tag. What I am currently posting is shown in the above under Update. Is that what you mean? Or is your way different?

Comment: @FlorianF. Sorry I didn't read it closely that you want me to post the `<form>` snippet. Not like post it to jquery. (Too much things) The `<form>` snippet is now updated above. Any clue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't post a file using ajax and form serialization.

You should check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4545089/1665540) which explains why.

However, you still have solutions :

- Not using ajax and just submitting the form using `enctype='multipart/form-data'` attribute on the form

```html
<form [...] enctype='multipart/form-data'></form>
```

- Using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FAPI%2FFormData%2FUsing_FormData_Objects#Sending_files_using_a_FormData_object)

```js
var formData = new FormData();

// HTML file input user's choice...
formData.append("userfile", fileInputElement.files[0]);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "http://foo.com/submitform.php");
request.send(formData);
```

- Using [File API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/?redirect_from_locale=fr)

```js
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function(e) {
  var rawData = reader.result;
}

reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
```

Comment: Voting down without a comment ? Why do i bother trying to help :)

Comment: I didn't know file can't be uploaded with serialization. I'll try the methods you provided. And btw, my reputation won't let me vote down...

Comment: So with your FormData method above. How do I get the response from the server?

Comment: There's a pretty good example using jQuery ajax in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8244082/1665540).

Comment: How do you get file element from Jasny file input?