# upload image using formdata ajax send to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I newbie in this webpage area and I was try to upload image to my file by using ajax and send it to php. But I have done some coding here. Can some one correct me where I'am wrong ?
here is my form with file upload and a button

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="">
    <input type="file" name="images" id="images" multiple="" />

    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="harlo">
</form>
```

Once I click on button the file will send it here and receive the src and ajax to php file
but I guess is about getting source problem. Need some one correct it for me.

```
(function upload() {

    var input2 = document.getElementById("harlo"), 

    formdata = false;



    if (window.FormData) {
        formdata = new FormData();

    }

    input2.addEventListener("click", function () {

        var i = 0, len = $('input[type="file"]')[0].files;

        for ( ; i < len.length; i++ ) {
            file = len.files[i];

            if (formdata) {
                formdata.append("images", file);
            }

        }

        if (formdata) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "upload.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: formdata,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (res) {
                    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML =  res; 
                }
            });
        }
    }, false);
}());

<?php

    foreach ($_FILES["images"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
        if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $name = $_FILES["images"]["name"][$key];
            move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$key], "uploads/" . $_FILES['images']['name'][$key]);
        }
    }

    echo "<h2>Successfully Uploaded Images</h2>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

```
$("form").on("submit", function(
    // Your ajax request goes here
    $.ajax({
        url: "upload.php",
       type: "POST",
       data: $("form").serialize(),
       processData: false,
       contentType: false,
       success: function (res) {
          $("#response").innerHTML = res;
       }
    });

    return false;
));
```

But there seems to be a problem with sending files trough ajax anyway.  Cause they're missed by the `serialize()` method because JS has no access to files content on users computer. So the form must be sent to the server to get the file data.

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4545089/1652031

Comment: how to i include test box value?formdata.append("user", input3);i have try this but show object html input and how to convert to value?

Comment: What's `formdata.append("user", input3);` And where do you like to append it?