# Laravel: Images removed from POST data

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having trouble retrieving any file data from my form post. I'm using the Laravel form Macros but I've also tried plain HTML inputs.

When I post the form there's no file input being posted, I've also tried dumping the post data in my controller just to double check. Not sure where I'm going wrong here...

Here's a quick rundown of the code:

```
{{ Form::open(array(
    "url"   => $formAction,
    "files" => true,
    "id"    => "settings-form",
    "class" => "form-horizontal"
)) }}

    {{ Form::file($name, array(
        "class" => "input-sm"
    )) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Input::file()`? As explained here: http://laravel.com/docs/requests#files

Comment: I have. There's no data even being posted is the problem though. It's almost as if the post data is being removed.

Comment: Use your browser's inspector to check the requests being made. There may be a redirect or something happening in between that you aren't noticing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the url attribute, try specifying a route:

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => 'myRoute.store', 'files' => true, 'class' => 'form form-horizontal']) }}
```

Or if you are updating an existing record:

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => ['myRoute.update', $modelId], 'files' => true, 'class' => 'form form-horizontal']) }}
```

Or if you want to use model-binding:

```
{{ Form::model($myModel, ['route' => ['myRoute.update', $model->id], 'files' => true, 'class' => 'form form-horizontal']) }}
```

That usually works for me, never had issues uploading this way.

Comment: Thanks but don't think this is the issue. The form posts properly, it's only file data that isn't showing up... any other input type posts to the controller just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... I was serializing my form data and submitting it via jQuery's AJAX function.

Better answer here if interested: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4545089/597546