# jQuery validation-plugin: validating multiple input files

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I would like to ask how to validate multiple file input using the jQuery validation-plugin.

Currently I have these codes but it doesn't work:

.html:

```html
<form id="uploadPhotoForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <table class= "uploadPhotoTable">
        <tr>
            <td>Photo</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input class="field" type="file" name="files[]" id="upload_photo" align='right' multiple /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
</form>
```

.js:

```
$('#uploadPhotoForm').validate({
    rules: {
      files: {
      required: true,
      extension: "png"
    }
    },
    messages:{
        files:{
           required : "Please upload atleast 1 photo",
           extension:"Only png file is allowed!"
        }       
    }
  });
```

I also will use this code to post to new PHP for processing. But it seems like in my uploadPhoto.php, `$_FILES['files']['tmp_name']` is undefined. May i know how to solve this?

```
if ($('#uploadPhotoForm').valid()) {       
    $.ajax({
        url: "inc/uploadPhoto.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:  new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(data){
           $("#error1").html(data);
        }           
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `'files[]'` instead of `files`, and if you doesn't add [additional-methods.js](http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.13.1/additional-methods.js), you will do it.

```
  $('#uploadPhotoForm').validate({
    rules: {
      'files[]': {
      required: true,
      extension: "png"
    }
    },
    messages:{
        'files[]':{
           required : "Please upload atleast 1 photo",
           extension:"Only png file is allowed!"
        }

    }
```

See [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mLmvzxb0/).

About serialize.
Please read this [how to do file upload using jquery serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545081/how-to-do-file-upload-using-jquery-serialization)

**Update:**

It will work

```
if ($('#uploadPhotoForm').valid()) {  
    var form = $('#uploadPhotoForm')[0]; //  [0], because you need to use standart javascript object here
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    $.ajax({
        url: "inc/uploadPhoto.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:  formData,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(data){
           $("#error1").html(data);
        }           
    });
}
```

Your code haven't work i think because `this` in `data:  new FormData(this),` not valid javascript form object.

Comment: thanks for ur ans... i have another question to ask regarding this..
usually i will use this code to post to new php for processing, but it seems like in my uploadPhoto.php, $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] is undefined..may i know how to solve this?
$.post('inc/uploadPhoto.php', $("#uploadPhotoForm").serialize(), function(data) {});

Comment: I added link in my answer.

Comment: it seems like it doesnt work for me... can u show me an example?

Comment: Select two files. One `png` and other `pdf`. It will not show validation message.

Answer (score 2):

For some one who might land on this page through google.I solved it using the following solution since it was not working properly with multiple uploads with different formats.

```
<input type="file" id="upload_files" name="uploaded_files[]"  required="required" multiple>
```

I made a custom validator method since the default validator was not validating multiple files properly.If I select 1st file as pdf and other one png.This example validates pdf,doc and docx files.

```
$(function() {
    $.validator.addMethod(
            "validate_file_type",
            function(val,elem) {
                console.log(elem.id);
                    var files    =   $('#'+elem.id)[0].files;
                console.log(files);
                for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++){
                    var fname = files[i].name.toLowerCase();
                    var re = /(\.pdf|\.docx|\.doc)$/i;
                    if(!re.exec(fname))
                    {
                        console.log("File extension not supported!");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            },
            "Please upload pdf or doc or docx files"
    );
    // Initialize form validation on the registration form.
    // It has the name attribute "registration"
    $("form[name='formname']").validate({
        // Specify validation rules
        rules: {
            'uploaded_files[]':{
                required: true,
                validate_file_type : true
            }
        },
        // Specify validation error messages
        messages: {

            'uploaded_files[]':{
                required : "Please upload atleast 1 document",
                /*accept:"Please upload .docx or .pdf files"*/
            }
        },
        // Make sure the form is submitted to the destination defined
        // in the "action" attribute of the form when valid
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });

});
```