# How to upload images via Ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I make a form for upload image:

```
gem paperclip install
```

Form:

```
<%= form_for(@image) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area(:description, rows: 4, class: 'form-control') %>
    <%= f.file_field :image, class: "desc_album" %>
    <%= f.submit 'Загрузить картинку', class: 'btn btn-default pull-right', id: 'loadImage' %>      
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def create  
  p '-------------------1'
  @image = Image.create(image_params)   

  if @image.save
    p '-------------------2'
    @image.update_attributes(user: current_user)

    render json: @image, :status => 200 
  else
    p '-------------------3'
    render json: @image.errors.full_messages, :status => 403 
  end
end
```

Loading images works OK.

The console displays:

```
Started POST "/images" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-01 15:47:16 +0300
Processing by ImagesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"PINHYvwaOerh2tFwIP8ad8Td8SPQmxh6m2Oy/uE0FzrdCn5UFRIf68KJ4/4fzzPLXITkScyhahlE+fU8mDUwEg==", "image"=>{"description"=>"gggggggggggggggggggggggggggg", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fd62c55f7d0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20150801-2493-1cks177.jpg>, @original_filename="f3.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image[image]\"; filename=\"f3.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Загрузить картинку"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 8]]
"-------------------1"
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/1779cf3aa50c413afc7e05adb7e1b0de20150801-2493-116a994.jpg'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/1779cf3aa50c413afc7e05adb7e1b0de20150801-2493-1wgxiwt.
...........
.............
......
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/1779cf3aa50c413afc7e05adb7e1b0de20150801-2493-1stgg9u.jpg'
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "images" ("description", "image_file_name", "image_content_type", "image_file_size", "image_updated_at", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["description", "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggg"], ["image_file_name", "f3.jpg"], ["image_content_type", "image/jpeg"], ["image_file_size", "8602"], ["image_updated_at", "2015-08-01 15:47:16 +0300"], ["created_at", "2015-08-01 12:47:16.575017"], ["updated_at", "2015-08-01 12:47:16.575017"]]
   (22.5ms)  COMMIT
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
"-------------------2"
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "images" SET "user_id" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "images"."id" = $3  [["user_id", 8], ["updated_at", "2015-08-01 12:47:16.677588"], ["id", 2]]
   (17.3ms)  COMMIT
Completed 200 OK in 459ms (Views: 0.7ms | ActiveRecord: 41.7ms)
```

I'd like to upload images via Ajax.js:

```
$('#new_image').on('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    url: '/images',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "JSON", 
    data: $('#new_image').serialize(),
    success: function(image){
      alert('im load success');
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
      alert(xhr.responseText);
    }        
  })
});
```

but this method does not work: the image is not loaded and console displays:

```
Started POST "/images" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-01 16:00:01 +0300
Processing by ImagesController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"uqqR6HtkkYDuhWoFHHCmll2mWuzEHfBtpMQ/A2hwivZbI6jekmy3gc3WWIsjQI8qxf9Phtgngg57XnjBEXGt3g==", "image"=>{"description"=>"ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg"}}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 8]]
"-------------------1"
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
"-------------------3"
Completed 403 Forbidden in 8ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

Comment: Change your `@image.save` to `@image.save!`. This will throw an error as to why it's not being saved, instead of just failing silently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the log file, your `ajax` doesn't pass an image file:.

First:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", ... "image"=>{"description"=>"gg..."}}
```

Second:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", ... "image"=>{"description"=>"gg...", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fd62c55f7d0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20150801-2493-1cks177.jpg>, @original_filename="f3.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name
```

Try to debug next line:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/images',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "JSON", 
    data: $('#new_image').serialize(),
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    success: function(image){
      alert('im load success');
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
      alert(xhr.responseText);
    }        
  })
```

Comment: thanks. solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545081/how-to-do-file-upload-using-jquery-serialization