# Send serialize data on kartik file input

Tags: widget, yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii-widgets

I am implementing `\kartik\file\FileInput` widget.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
            echo FileInput::widget([
                'name' => 'dataSiswa',
                'options' => [
                    'multiple' => false
                ],
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'uploadUrl' => Url::toRoute('pesertadidikuploadproses'),
                    'uploadExtraData' => ['folderId' => ""],
                    'showUpload' => true
                ],
                'pluginEvents' => [
                    'fileuploaded' => "function(event, data, previewId, index) {
                                            $('#pesan').show();
                                            $('#pesan').html(data.response.pesan);
                                        }"
                ]
            ]);
            ?>
```

I want the value of `uploadExtraData` should be get as serialize data form --> `$('#formid').serialize();`

Answer (score 0):

Like said in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545081/how-to-do-file-upload-using-jquery-serialization), you can't direct access to files on a user computer. One technique is to use and iframe to do the submission and that way you won't have to refresh the page.
So use [this plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) and just do something as below:

```
$(function() {
  $('#ifoftheform').ajaxForm(function(result) {
     alert('the form was successfully processed');
  });
});
```