# jquery form serialization issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am doing form serialization to send the file name to the server.
This serialization values is empty . I am expecting the file name over here.

My form is having a html file upload element. Which shows the file name in the right side when you select the file.

```
HTML:
    <form name="MyForm" id="MyForm" method="post" action=cgi_path">
    <input type="file" name="filename" id="my_file">
    </form>  

SCRIPT:
    var frm_data = $("#MyForm").serialize(); // This is empty
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "file upload cgi url",
                data: frm_data
            });
```

1. How to take the file name with out serializing this form?
2. Is there any problem with form serialization for file name?

Thanks

Comment: can you also post the html?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545081/how-to-do-file-upload-using-jquery-serialization

Comment: Are you just trying to send the file name, or the file as well?

Comment: keep an action to the form. and utilize that for your ajax url property, by just giving url:$("#formId").attr("action").

Answer (score 1):

Files can only be uploaded with AJAX by using FormData, not serialisation (since you are sending more than just the filename).

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: new FormData($("#MyForm").get(0)),
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST'
})
```

Comment: What exactly is empty? Is your (I assume) MVC method receiving null? How are you receiving this request?

Comment: When i keep the debug there . the new Formdata{} is shown as empty.

Comment: My only guess is that the form element is malformed from the lack of opening quote (") on the action.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have an `<input id="some_ID" name="some_name" type="file" />`

so, you just need to pick the element "content"

```
var file = {}
$('#some_ID').change(function(){
    file.content = this.files[0];
    file.name = file.name;
    file.size = file.size;
    file.type = file.type;
});
```

then you just need to post it to the server.

Comment: Assuming he has what exactly? You forgot to write the word after "an".

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to serialize the form to get the file name. To retrieve it just call

```
var filename = document.getElementById("my_file").files[0];
```

or this with jQuery

```
var filename = $('#my_file')[0].files[0]
```