# Is there a way to upload an image before checkout completion without a plugin?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, file, woocommerce

I have this plugin I've made for uploading an image before an order can be completed, but for the life of me I can't get the image to upload. $_FILES will always return nothing, I'm not sure why though. I'd like it to be that the checkout won't be completed until the image is uploaded, is this even possible?
*I've been told that woocommerce uses ajax for the cart

```
<?php
    /*
        @package            UploadTest
        @wordpress_plugin
        Plugin Name:            UploadTest
        Plugin URI:             null
        Description:            
        Author:                 Goodship
        Version:                0.0.2
        Author URI:             www.Goodship.co.za
    */

    function add_image(){
        $testLog = fopen(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )."testicle.txt","w") or exit ("Unable to open file!");
        //if they DID upload a file...
        if($_FILES['testUpload']['name']){
            //if no errors...
            if(!$_FILES['testUpload']['error']){
                //now is the time to modify the future file name and validate the file
                $new_file_name = strtolower($_FILES['testUpload']['tmp_name']); //rename file
                if($_FILES['testUpload']['size'] > (1024000)) //can't be larger than 1 MB
                {
                    $valid_file = false;
                    $message = 'Oops!  Your file\'s size is to large.';
                }

                //if the file has passed the test
                if($valid_file){
                    //move it to where we want it to be
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['testUpload']['tmp_name'], plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'uploads/'.$new_file_name);
                    $message = 'Congratulations!  Your file was accepted.';
                }
            }
            //if there is an error...
            else
            {
                //set that to be the returned message
                $message = 'Ooops!  Your upload triggered the following error:  '.$_FILES['testUpload']['error'];
            }
        }
        fwrite ($testLog ,$message);
        fwrite ($testLog ,var_dump($_FILES));
        fclose ($testLog);
    }

    add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'add_image');


    function add_checkout_notice() {
        echo    '<input type="file" name="testUpload" />';
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details', 'add_checkout_notice');

    ?>
```

Comment: are you submitting checkout form via ajax??

Comment: For the checkout completion just use JS to check if the input field of the image is empty or not. If it's empty put a `disabled` on a complete checkout button, so that you cannot complete the checkout. Then once you've uploaded the image (I'm assuming JS must be involved here somehow), just remove the `disabled` from the checkout button.
As for why it doesn't upload, no clue to that...

Comment: @Maha Dev the checkout is submitted normally, with whatever process woocommerce uses

Comment: @dingo_d the input field is definitely not empty, but $_FILES is for whatever reason

Comment: you might update the question to include that woo-commerce uses ajax to handle the cart. you wont get a proper answer otherwise

Comment: @David ok, I've added it

Comment: if your `$_FILES` variable is completely empty, then I'd be curious to see what your html form looks like, in particular the input name and form action.

Comment: Hi @Jeff Puckett, I've inserted the input into the form used for capturing billing and shipping information in woocommerces checkout form. the input I use resides in a form with the following properties: `<form name="checkout" method="post" class="checkout woocommerce-checkout" action="http://localhost:81/wordpress/checkout/" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <input type="file" name="testUpload">`

Answer (score 4):

You need to call below function in your child theme.

```
function add_image($order_id){
  // Do your code of upload image.
} 
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'add_image',  1, 1  );
```

Comment: unfortunately, there was no effect, and the test file logs nothing

Answer (score 2):

Woocommerce checkout will always happens via Ajax ( I am not sure from what version it's been like this )

`PLUGIN-DIR/woocommerce/assets/frontend/checkout.js` this is the file which is responsible for the checkout action.

So uploading files from checkout page is not possible unless you intended to modify the `checkout.js` file by yourself.

If you still prefer uploading file from checkout page, you may refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545081/how-to-do-file-upload-using-jquery-serialization).

Answer (score 1):

Have you given a look at Advanced Custom Field? https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

You can easily achieve what you are trying to do.

Have a look at this https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acfupload_prefilter/

Comment: I need to do this without plugins, the amount of items uploaded will be indeterminable on post edit, and will vary.