# Can submit the file and the other field in the form once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want to use  jquery to submit the form ，**the form with text field  and file field** ,but it just submit the **text field "groupId"**  , I can't  submit the groupId with file  field . 
the request header just 
**Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8**

**My problem is : can i submit the groupId field  and  file field  once ?If can , what should I do?**

the code below

```
<form  id="submitForm"  >                      
           <div class="form-group">
             <label for="exampleInputEmail1" >groupId</label>
             <input type="text" name="groupId" class="form-control" >
           </div>

          <div class="form-group">
             <label for="exampleInputFile" >File input</label>
             <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleInputFile" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
                 <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">This is some placeholder block-level help text for the above input. It's a bit lighter and easily wraps to a new line.</small>
          </div>
          <button id="newItemSubmitButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" >cancel</button>
    </form>
```

js code

```
                var submitForm = $('#submitForm');
                $("#newItemSubmitButton").click(function (e) {
                    console.log("submit");  
                        e.preventDefault();
                        console.log("after preventDefault");
                        $.ajax({
                            data:submitForm.serialize() ,
                            url: "./testSubmit",
                            type: "post",
                            success: function (data) {
                                // $("#form_output").html(data);
                                console.log("hello");
                            },
                            error: function (jXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                alert(errorThrown);
                            }
                        });

                    $('#newItem').modal('hide');
                    return false;
                });
```

Comment: Did you try a Google search atleast once ?

Comment: See if this helps.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5976031/2592042

Comment: i have search many time , i  just  know that  file  with the multipart/form-data , i have read the rfc 1867 but it just overview this file .

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545081/how-to-do-file-upload-using-jquery-serialization and multipart data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax