# Submitting 2 symfony forms with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, symfony

I'm trying to submit 2 symfony forms in one submit using ajax

```
var data = $('#facebookPostTargetForm').serialize();
data = data.concat("\r\n", $('#facebookPostForm').serialize());
$.ajax({
    url: '{{ path('facebookpostwizard_new') }}',
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data){
    //console.log(data);
    alert('OK');
    }
    });
```

almost everything is working properly except the case that in my controller when I use `$form->handleRequest($request)` i get some trouble getting the last field of first form(mostly _token so `$form->isValid()` always return false) and first field of second one!!!! I don't put a snippet of my controller here because if I only submit one form everything works perfect, it seems to be related to the data.concat() but I've tried a lot of things and it doesn't work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "some trouble" and "doesn't work" means what, exactly? Descriptions of error messages and/or unexpected behaviour would be more appropriate than these vague statements. But...why are you adding line breaks in front of your serialised form data??? What is that for? I doubt the server is going to understand what you're trying to submit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing your PHP code, I can only guess what the issue is. But I suspect you are not handling the Array that you receive correctly. Or rather, you are trying to build something totally different from what you are actually sending.

[concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) does not concatenate strings but Arrays. If you just want to concatenate the serialized query strings of the forms, you can simply use `+` operator like this:

```
var data = $('#facebookPostTargetForm').serialize() + '&' + $('#facebookPostForm').serialize();
```

This will make one big query string from both forms and you will have them available as POST variables in the `$request` object. Note that this will only work if the fields in both forms are named differently. If a field has the same name, form2 will override form1.

If you use the same field names and want to handle the forms separately, you should post an object instead of a form:

```
var data = {
    'form1': $('#facebookPostTargetForm').serializeArray(),
    'form2': $('#facebookPostForm').serializeArray()
};
```

This will submit an object ob objects (or a multidimensional associative array in PHP speech). You can then access them in PHP like this:

```
$form1 = $request->get('form1');
$field1 = $form1['field1']
```

Comment: good point @masterfloda I deleted my post since I noticed it is redundat

Comment: Hi it was very usefull, just to say that I use concat in strings based on this https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_methods.asp, I was just missing the fact of using '&' in concat and it's working like a charm!! Ithink I can't mark this as an answer and it's a shame!!! Thanks anyway!!!!

Comment: @masterfloda is there a similar way to "var data = $('#facebookPostTargetForm').serialize() + '&' + $('#facebookPostForm').serialize();"  but uploading files in one of related form???? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: @RubislandyRodriguez Not with plain jQuery. For this, Juan's deleted answer would have been helpful :-) The solution is the ajaxForm plugin. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4545089/7933618

Comment: @masterfloda I found this: var target = $('#facebookPostTargetForm').serializeArray();

                var data = new FormData($('#facebookPostForm')[0]);

                for (var i=0; i<target.length; i++)
                    data.append(target[i].name, target[i].value);